# Debug output in all views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

I'm currently developing a new Rails 3 app. All my instance variables defined in the controllers will automatically be debugged in my views. This happens both in development and production mode.

As much as this is helpful, I'd really like to get rid of that because it destroys the HTML layout partially.

For example I have in my controllers index actions:

```
respond_with(@articles = Article.published.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(5))
```

In the view you will automatically see something similiar like the output of <%= debug @articles %>, although I never call inspect or debug in my views.

A sample picture to demonstrate the whole issue:

http://www.diigo.com/item/image/16wox/padm?size=o

My Gemfile looks like this: https://gist.github.com/1080104

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question. Is the output exactly `<%= debug @articles %>` or is the output actually a yaml formated object?

Comment: Actually I'm not asking to debug any variables. I'm trying to get rid of that automatic debug behaviour I have. Please see the linked screenshot

Answer (score 1):

You should create a method in your application helper module:

```
def debug_all &block
  excluded_vars = ["@lookup_context", "@view_context_class", "@action_has_layout"]
  controller.instance_variables.each do |var|
     unless var.at(1)== "_" or excluded_vars.include?(var)
       yield var
      end
   end
end
```

And in your application layout:

```
<% debug_all do |var| %>
  <%= "variable name: #{var} " %>
  <%= eval(var).inspect %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Just realized my whole loop is useless. You're just looking for the inspect method.