# Turning off automatic debug output in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

[Debug output in all views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677481/debug-output-in-all-views)

This question shows my problem, but there was no real answer given. Is there a way to simply turn off the automatic debug output in Rails?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such thing as automatic debug output in views. Can you please post the code of your view and explain what exactly is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. I had written this:
`- flash.each do |key, value|`
instead of
`= flash.each do |key, value|`
Subtle difference, but it makes all the difference.